# Eclipse plugin: attach a java process to a code launch

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So I am doing an eclipse plugin for educational purposes.
My goal now is to have an additional java thread running , when the Run button is hit.
So, alongside with the normally launched programme , I want to have my own plugin code running (which I specified in the plugin).

I thought about trying to create a new java thread , running my code when I execute `DebugUITools.launch(config, mode);` . 
But I am not sure how I would attach the thread to the launched process so that I could stop the thread too...

I also thought about creating java launch configuration for my plugin code, but it's probably impossible because as far as I can see, we need a `Project` for that.

So, are there any possibilities to programmatically attach new threads to a launched program? Or maybe create a second launch configuration out of plugin code, and launch it?

I hope I was able to explain my struggle to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Launch runs the code in a completely new JVM. You can't take a thread in the current JVM and move it to a different one.

A second launch configuration in your code would only end up launching yet another JVM which doesn't get you anywhere.

You would have the modify the existing launch configuration to add a jar containing your code and change the program entry point to point to your code so you can start your thread.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer again. If i change the entry point of the launch configuration, then the program that would normally be launched , will not launch. Correct me if I am wrong. Maybe i could try invoking my methods, but then there is no sence in the plugin...

Comment: Your code would have to call the `main` method of the other program.

Comment: So, I have changed the entry point of my application but now i get an error that the plugin code is not in the path... Now i try to edit classpath using `wcTemp.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_CLASSPATH, "/C:/Users/EMAKMEL/Desktop/eclipse/DLaunchConf_1.0.0.jar");` but no success... Do you know the right way to set the classpath of the launch configuration?